# Gstreamer multiple sink switching

Tags: python, gstreamer

*I want to create a pipeline through Gstreamer such that it has multiple sinks.*
I need to switch between those sinks as well ie. I put a command then data comes out through sink1 put another command data comes out through sink2 etc.
Stuck in this problem from many days. Can somebody help?
I am using the approach of demuxer and tweaking the demuxer_callback to attain objective but nothing seems working.

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets for reference?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.